# Laravel 5 pass route to template with view composer

Tags: php, laravel

I need to add specific scripts to my footer template for when users are browsing different pages on the site.

I'm using :

```
public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('partials.jsinclude',function($view)
        {

           $view->with('variable',{{how to pass the route here}});
        });
    }
```

My footer template:

```
<section id="footer-top" class="section">
<!-- Start Footer -->
<footer class="footer">
  //some code here:
</footer>
</section>
<!--/ End Footer -->
@include ('partials.jsinclude')
```

so for example when a user is on the blogs/taylor_swift page
it would include the script files for only blogs/js/taylor_swift at the end of scripts partial template

how do I pass to the `partials.jsinclude` template the current page the viewer is on so for example "blogs" and "taylor_swift" when a user nagivates to **mypage.com/blogs/taylor_swift**

Comment: Do you mean you want to add the `partials.jsinclude` for the two pages or you want to pass data to it

Comment: I want to pass data to it specifically the name of the controller and the name of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('partials.jsinclude', function ($view) {
        $action = request()->route()->getAction();

        $controller = class_basename($action['controller']);

        list($controller, $action) = explode('@', $controller);
        $url = request()->url();
        $view_name = str_replace('.', '-', $view->getName());
        $view->with(compact('controller', 'action','url','view_name'));
    });
}
```

This loads the `controller,action,url,view_name` variables in your `view`

Answer (score 1):

For `Blogs` you do `getPrefix` and for `taylor_swift` you do `getActionName`, so you pass the parameters to the view like this:

['prefix' => $route->getPrefix(), 'action' => $route->getActionName()]